# Submit a Gravity Form as other user

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I'm looking for a script that will display a drop-down list on my gravity form and show all the current users registered on WordPress.

When selecting a user, this form submission will be submitted in the name of the selected user. There is a proposed solution [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/296340/gravity-forms-submit-form-as-another-user).

But it is not working.